# Access Query - [col]/[col].[col]?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Just inherited an Access database and trying to figure some things out. For the life of me, I have no idea what this query means.

```
SELECT [col1]/[col2].[col3]...
```

Its like the `[col1]/[col2]` is the table name and `[col3]` is the column. But instead of a table, it is math function (dividing two columns) followed by the column name.  `SELECT table.column...`.

I thought this might be inherent to someone with Access experience (or maybe this is some SQL that I am not familiar with). If it is not just comment and I will post all of the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT [coly]/[table].[colx]...
```

Comment: Ahh, yes.  Thanks.  "`[col2]`" is both a table and column name.